# Quantifying Superiority of Golden Section vs Binary Search vs Brent on Continuous Function

Tags: search

This concerns algorithms for searching for the minimum of a continuous unidimensional unimodal function.  The simplest method is three points, and bi-sectioning.  The golden-section search seems more natural.  Although Brent seems a little better yet.

I am trying to find a reference as to how much more efficient these searches are relative to one another.

I need something like an "expected number of function samples to reach tolerance xtol."  One can assume a uniform distribution of the minimum, and some distribution of the brackets, perhaps.

does someone have a good reference?

Comment: A rigorous analysis would require assumptions about the curvature of the function which are hard to make.

Comment: is "superiority" just a philosophical concept here?